# How to override var in the javascript class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I learn to create my own library. This is new for me. I start learn with [this library](https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager/blob/master/lib/undomanager.js#L110), if you see, I have similar `clear function` like that library, but my code didn't replace `var history`.

Init value: `var history = [];`

Show(): return `[]`

Add ('asd'): `history[0] = 'asd';`

Show(): return `[asd]`

Clear: revert var history to empty `var history = []`

Show(): return `[asd]` what I expect is `[]`

Here is my code:

```js
;(function() {
  'use strict';
  var testLib = function() {
    var index = -1,
      history = [];
    return {
      add: function(data) {
        history[history.length] = data;
      },
      show: function() {
        return history;
      },
      clear: function() {
        var index = -1,
          history = [];
      }
    };
  };

  window.testLib = testLib;
}());

$(function() {
  var mylib = new testLib();
  mylib.add('asdasd');
  console.log(mylib.show());
  mylib.clear();
  console.log(mylib.show()); //expect: [] empty array
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "overriding var"?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 : sry for my grammar. i means to revert back var history to default value.

Comment: Your vars are not visible outside the iife. You need history to be either a global var or a private var using a setter

Comment: its because you are redeclaring the history variable in your function. remove the the comma ,   after = -1 and put a semi colon ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `var` in your `clear` method:

```
clear: function() {
    index = -1;
    history = [];
}
```

You are declaring new variables instead of modifying the ones in your closure. In modern ECMAScript, you might want to consider creating your library as a "class":

```
class History{
    // ...
    clear() {
        this.history = [];
        this.index = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: A class will increase complexity. Singletons should be objects.

Comment: @AluanHaddad An instance from a "class" *is* an object with its prototype pointed the class definition.

Comment: damn. i miss that. omg. i can create class like PHP , lol XD . thanks you very much for the additional information. i really appreciate this

Comment: I know. I am only saying that I would prefer using an _object_ (`{}`) over a a _class_ that has to be `[[Construct]]`ed (`new class {}()`). Since there is but one object, you will also not improve performance by sharing method definitions.

Comment: Ultimately it depends on the use case. For libraries it usually is the case that it should return a singleton, but in OP's case a class is probably better but that's purely personal opinion.

Comment: so what i need to use? create js library or object is really new for me. even i have experience in js/jquery since 3 years ago

Comment: @plonknimbuzz It's your choice. Performance difference is negligible.

Comment: can you tell me plz, i dont know about this. i will search in google too ofc

Comment: Right. This answer is completely correct. My point is stylistic.

Comment: owh,. i got that. after google. thanks to every 1 here.

Answer (score 2):

Just set your variables in the proper scope ;)
First in your sample, you redefine variables in your `clear` function, by using the keyword `var`.

Then, from my experience, it is simpler to set everything in the same object and not have private scopes inside your object. This way, you can work in a more flexible way!

So, do not use `var`, set your properties in the object you return, and use `this` and it will work fine!

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var testLib = function() {
    return {
      index: -1,
      history: [],
      add: function(data) {
        this.history[this.history.length] = data;
      },
      show: function() {
        return this.history;
      },
      clear: function() {
        this.index = -1;
        this.history = [];
      }
    };
  };

  window.testLib = testLib;
}());

$(function() {
  var mylib = testLib();
  mylib.add('asdasd');
  console.log(mylib.show());
  mylib.clear();
  console.log(mylib.show()); //expect: [] empty array
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Downvoters please elaborate why! Looks legit to have private vars with setters and getters

Comment: I downvoted because you recommend very poor coding practices. Furthermore, your code is not correct. You should not be invoking a factory with `new`

Comment: @AluanHaddad what is wrong with this version? Can you elaborate? Because I don't see what is wrong here... It is just simple but i don't see why it's SO bad.

Comment: @sjahan You shouldn't return an object if you are using `new`. The `new` keyword will already generate a new object for you. At this point it's just a normal function instead of a constructor.

Comment: Well, I agree. Though, the mistake was in OP code, not especially in mine. I fixed the code in my post anyway!